# Can nociceptors die because of too much mechanical stress?

Tags: neuroscience, sensation, pain, adaptation, human-physiology

In martial art people hit their body (e.g., with small bean bags) to become more insensitive to pain. Can the sensory neurons die during this procedure? I think this is just an urban legend. Instead, I think the skin receptors desensitize, but they don't degenerate by the constant mechanical stress. However, I cannot find any research in the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, adaptation of peripheral receptors, including pain receptors, is *transient* [(Giniatullin & Nistri, 2013)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3854565/)

Instead, my educated guess is that the increase in *subjective pain threshold* plays an important role. Pain thresholds differ between the sexes [(Chesterton et al., 2003)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304395902003305), and depend on disease and physical status [(Kosak et al., 1996)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304395902003305). Repeated exposure to painful stimuli hardens one mentally (I have practiced martial arts for two decades ).

Morever, there is an interesting answer on [Martial Arts SE](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/) on the question [How should I expect my fist to change over time from punching?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/375/how-should-i-expect-my-fist-to-change-over-time-from-punching) Here it is shown that extensive training stimulates the growth of additional skin and bone. Extra skin (*calluses*) may dampen the impact of painful pressure stimuli.

**References**
- [Chesterton et al., *pain* (2003); **101**(3): 259–66](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304395902003305)
- [Giniatullin & Nistri, *Front Cell Neurosci* (2013); **7**(245): 1-9](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3854565/)
- [Kosak et al., *pain* (1996); **64**(3): 415–23](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304395902003305)

Comment: Ok. I can accept this. Btw. the technique I referred is called as "bone hardening". I have found a lot of interesting articles about bone remodeling. It appears to depend on mechanoreceptors. http://www.researchgate.net/publication/239942205_Osteocytes_are_not_only_mechanoreceptive_cells http://www.bme.sunysb.edu/people/faculty/documents/2012-gene-mechanotransduction.pdf http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1063458412000192 http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00018-005-5175-3